# Introductory and except theroms and lemmas... part others getting Italized

Tags: italic

I have tried to see what is that code which is italicized the introductory part of second chapter and whatever I am writing except lemma, propositions etc as shown in pictures. But in chapter 0 everything seems good they are not getting italicized.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,amssymb, amsthm,}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{propn}[thm]{Proposition}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setstretch{1.15}
\hyphenpenalty
\exhyphenpenalty
\begin{document}
\newpage

\chapter{Preliminaries \& Notations}
\vspace{1cm}


Throughout these notes A
\newpage


simpler and eye soothing form
$$K_1(A) = \frac{GL(A)}{E(A)}$$  
\newpage
\chapter{Cohn's Example} 
    \vspace{1cm}
In the last chapter we
```

In the last chapter we proved that for a Euclidean ring $A$ subgroup
\end{document}

I am attaching screenshots and latex file so that someone can tell me what to change.
[image: Chapter 2]
[image: Chapter 0]

[Latex zip file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FBoUuDIuM8e3xPiOrrFPR9yBxKkj2geV/view?usp=share_link).

I don't have much knowledge of latex I have learned it to write project so please if possible treat me as naive in this field.

Thank you

Comment: Please never use screenshots for code. It's hard to read, isn't compatible with search and most of all prevents people from copy-pasting your code to test it. Provide your code directly (between triple quotes for formatting) in [Minimal Working Example form](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: @Miyase But I have provided the latex file itself so can you have a look at it?

Comment: Some of us sit behind firewalls, at least during parts of the day, and aren't allowed to download zip files...

Comment: @mico Now i have provided what packages i am using. Can you see any problem?

Comment: You really need to show the code immediately before and after `\chapter{Cohn's Example}`.

Comment: Off-topic: One really shouldn't use `$$` in a LaTeX document to initiate and terminate a display-math group. For more information on this subject, please see [Why is `\[ ... \]`  preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)

Comment: Are you perhaps using `\thm Statement of the theorem\endthm`, perhaps? Or some other code that uses `\thm`?

Comment: Yes I have used \thm for stating theorems. Should I have used \begin{thm} \end{thm}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very simple. You're using

```
\propn $[GL(A), GL(A)] = E(A) = [E(A), E(A)].$
```

which is wrong syntax.

It ***must*** be

```
\begin{propn}
$[GL(A), GL(A)] = E(A) = [E(A), E(A)].$
\end{propn}
```

The same, of course, with `\thm` that ***must*** be

```
\begin{thm}
Statement
\end{thm}
```

By the way, `$$` is not a LaTeX construct. Replace with `\[...\]`.

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg . You made my day. I was struggling for hours.:)